# VIM: Is it possible to add custom behavior when using /c with the substitute command?

Tags: vim, gvim, vimscript

There's been a few cases where it would be convenient to hook into the search and replace behavior for certain things.  For example, I have the following mapping in my vimrc:

nnoremap n nzzzv

Which centers the screen every time you advance to the next match.  This works well but does not apply when doing a %s//c command.  Is there a way to hook into when the user selects one of the confirmation options y/n/q/q/l/etc. so that you can trigger commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround for your particular use case of centering the currently substituted line is to

```
:set scrolloff=999
```

before the `:substitute` command. That has the same effect of centering the current line as your `zz` command.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not. The usual way to hook into this would be through an

```
:autocmd CursorMoved * ...
```

but that event isn't fired while in the `:substitute///c` query loop. Think of that as a special kind of mode with many restrictions; it would be very difficult to allow custom functionality in there while maintaining the correct search state.

You would have to reimplement the `:substitute` functionality yourself. Maybe you can use a `:help sub-replace-expression` with the query in there; I haven't yet tried whether user interaction is possible then.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Ingo Karkat's suggestion to use the scrolloff option I ended up going with this:

```
command! -nargs=1 CC set scrolloff=999|exec <f-args>|set scrolloff=0
```

So now you can just run "CC %s//c" and it will center the cursor temporarily during the command.  It's tempting to find an abbreviation or something for this but I couldn't think of anything that would work reliably.